# What are "positive theory" and "political economy theory"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Baron, 1993](https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/faculty-research/working-papers/economics-politics-regulation-perspectives-agenda-approaches) noted that pharmaceuticals can be studied vaccine regulation using normative theory (e.g. regulation of vaccines under incomplete information about clinical trials, particularly for the state-sponsored candidate vaccines such as Sputnik V, CoronaVac, and Covaxin), **positive theory** (e.g. political action by politicians or activists to streamline the vaccine approval process), **political economy theory** (e.g. stringent vaccine regulation as a function of interests and the associated political action), and even the **sociology of organizations** (e.g. why firms seek regulatory approval in some countries and not others).

I tried to search the meaning of "[positive theory](https://sk.sagepub.com/reference/ethics/n583.xml#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20a%20positive%20theory,express%20what%20ought%20to%20be.)" that

"In general, a positive theory is a theory that attempts to explain how the world works in a value-free way"
So, in general, positive theory talking about "what is" without judgment. However, I do not know how Baron can link this definition with the example above.

Apart from that, I did a search for "political economy theory" but I cannot find the meaning explanation, could you please help me to explain it and tell me why the definition can link to the example above?

Comment: Did you read the paper you linked to? the first 5 paragraphs describe the approaches in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In economics, a **positive theory** explains how an initial state of affairs considered to be essentially factual will evolve or end up under certain assumptions about rational behavior, without regard to whether the process or ultimate ends are socially or morally desirable.

A **normative theory** explains how things must be arranged initially for rational behavior to lead to a process and ultimate end that are considered socially or morally desirable.

Other social sciences may have different definitions.

When reading an academic paper, you must know the definitions of the technical jargon of the field to have much hope of understanding the paper.